# Recognizing MSSQL Service Broker sender side error messages

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I have SQL Service Broker set up between two servers over network and it is working alright. I'm implementing error processing at the moment. I have stored procedures attached to both queues to process messages.

In the cases when sending a message fails, such as when attempting to send malformed XML, the message stays in the sender queue. The transmission status is

> Service Broker received an error message on this conversation. Service
>   Broker will not transmit the message; it will be held until the
>   application ends the conversation.

When querying the queue (stored procedures turned off for debugging) with `select * from sys.transmission_queue`, the `is_conversation_error` and `is_end_of_dialog` fields are `0` and `message_type_name` is the same I used when sending, instead of the usual error type.

Is there a way to recognize such messages in the queue? My automatic sender queue is processing them as normal messages at the moment.

Comment: As an alternative, you can turn off message validation in the contract and, upon processing the message on the receive side, chuck it into an errored message table when you can't cast the message to xml.

Comment: It is funny actually, I have 'Validation = None', yet it still seems to check XML.

Comment: Weird. Does the contract look that way on both sides (i.e. initiator and target)?

Comment: @BenThul Turns out I had not updated my queues and their associated contracts after updating message types :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A malformed XML error will send back to your dialog an error message. This will be enqueued in your application queue and your app has to deal with it, as it must deal with any error message in its queue.

Note that you are confusing the *sender* queue with the `transmission_queue`. The sender queue is an ordinary queue created with `CREATE QUEUE`, and is the queue associated with your sending service. The error message I'm talking about is deposited in your sender queue and you can retrieve it with `RECEIVE`. The **`transmission_queue`** is an internal table owned by system that contains messages pending delivery. You cannot `RECEIVE` from the `transmission_queue`.

Judging from your post I guess your application is missing handling of messages in the sender queue. Even if your logical message flow is always from service 'A' to service 'B', you *must* have message handling for 'A' service queue as well. If nothing else, it is necessary for handling errors.

Comment: Great point about confusing the queues! I have a procedure on the sender queue for receiving replies to request (in A - B - A fashion). I will check if I can solve my problem tomorrow when I get back to work, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yep, there it was, with error status, on the sender queue, as I was looking at the wrong queue. Thank you!